# Broken links to documentation tutorials

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Wolfram with V12 is rewriting and updating (or perhaps has finished) the documentation.  Part of the process involves combining several short, related tutorials into a single "Tech Note."  In effect, more or less, they are combining subsections of the old *Mathematica Book* into the corresponding sections.  Unfortunately, they are not forwarding the old URLs to the new ones.  They updated the links within the documentation to the new ones, but this still leaves some problems:

- The site has a lot of dead links to the old tutorials.
- Old notebooks in which users have documentation links have dead links to tutorials (I have such that I provide to my students).

The second is irrelevant to the site, but the first is important.  It took me probably 20 minutes to find the new links to the three tutorials in [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed/8831#8831)

It didn't occur to me until later that I could have found hints in  *The Mathematica Book*  to the title of the new tutorial.  The search mechanism in *Mathematica* failed me, or I failed it.  In any case, it will still be time-consuming to find and fix the links by hand, I think.

*Is there a good way to fix the dead links?*

Comment: I have a bot which specializes in finding (and sometimes automatically fixing) broken links. I'll see what I can do after I'm back from holiday, if a better solution isn't found in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I finally got to a point where I could reconfigure my bot for this problem, I noticed that the [three links you fixed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/8831/revisions) in the answer you mentioned (listed below) automatically redirect to the new location.

- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

So I guess Wolfram solved this problem by itself.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I'm glad they thought of it.  Or maybe they saw this Q&A.